# passing class object as parameter to a function

Tags: php

```
include_once 'showData.php'; 
class dbInsertion { 
function db_insertShow($showData_obj)
{}
```

$showData is a class object how can i get its data members in this db_insertShow function

here is the class showdata

```
class ShowData {
  var $show_id;
  var $type_id;
  var $priority;
  var $name;
  var $sDescription;
  var $lDescription;
  var $bookinguntil;
  var $runtime;
  var $matinee;
  var $evening;
  var $pricefrom;
}
```

Comment: pass it as parameter to the function ?

Comment: are you aware , that we do not define class variables with `var` since 5.0 (that's 2004th) ?

Comment: Down voters should leave a comment here so a newbie can know what his/her fault and can ask questions in a better way.

Comment: i have change my class variables to private and also make getter and setter

Comment: Can you please better describe which part of the PHP manual was not so clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your class you can retrieve the members like this:

```
class dbInsertion { 
    function db_insertShow($showData_obj)
    {
        $show_id = $showData_obj->show_id;
        ...
    } 
}
```

Also you might want to have a look at the concept of getters and setters. Essentially they are just methods that are used to retrieve and set members. The bonus you get out of using getters and setters is that you can do extra stuff that might be required when retrieving the member. For this to make sense you should define your members as private though.

```
class ShowData {
    private $show_id;

    public function setShow_id($show_id) {
        $this->show_id = $show_id;
    }

    public function getShow_id() {
        return $this->show_id;
    }
}
```

Then, instead of the above example, you can access the members like this:

```
class dbInsertion { 
    function db_insertShow($showData_obj)
    {
        $show_id = $showData_obj->getShow_id();
        ...
    } 
}
```